# Destroy method not called properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

```
Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0.0
```

In my views/users/index.html.erb, I have the following:

```
  <% @users.each do |u| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= u.first %></td>
      <td><%= u.last %></td>
      <%= render partial: "layouts/show_edit_del_buttons", locals: {my_model: u} %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

My views/layouts/_show_edit_del_buttons.html.erb, I have the following:

```
    <td>
      <%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-info', title: 'View', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
      <% end %>
    <td>
      <%= link_to [:edit, my_model], class: 'btn btn-warning', title: 'Edit', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right' do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to my_model, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger', title: 'Delete', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right'  do %>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
      <% end %>
    </td>
```

In my controllers/users_controller.rb, I have the following:

```
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The Users Index is displayed properly. When I select the Edit or View buttons, it behaves properly. When I select the Delete button, I get the popup: Are you sure, and when I click on OK, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

and it points to the following line in the controller:

```
@user.destroy
```

The views/layouts/_show_edit_del_buttons.html.erb partial is called from the Index action, defined in the users controller:

```
def index
  @users = User.all
end
```

Any ideas?

## Additional notes:

I modified the partial as follows:

```
<%= render partial: "layouts/show_edit_del_buttons", locals: {my_model: u, my_id: u.id} %>
```

and the controller as follows:

```
def destroy(id)
  @user = User.where(:id => id)[0] if id
  @user.destroy
```

Now, it looks like the params are passed properly. but I'm still getting an error:

```
ArgumentError at /users/19
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Request parameters  
 {"_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"tjNjgGzaH3Rxez1sYhn/NyZQMUqg8vUDhcmxoZI0KBs=", "action"=>"destroy", "controller"=>"users", "id"=>"19"}
```

When I did try (from the console) the following:

```
@user = User.where(:id => id)[0]
```

and then:

```
@user.destroy
```

The record was indeed destroyed

## Solution:

In my routes.rb, I had:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :index]
```

I changed it to:

```
resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :index, :destroy]
```

That worked

Comment: Yes, this I already know. Did you read my question? I am looping through @users

Comment: What you are trying to say?

Comment: I thought that <% @users.each do |u| %> is a loop. There's no need for your personal attacks, and who's the WE?

Comment: How to initialize it is what I'm asking for. Rails dealt fine with the other two methods (edit and show), but it's having trouble with destroy, even through it understands it's the user model. I tried adding a conditional to initialize user in destroy if user is nil, bit it did not work

Comment: Once more, and the reason why I asked if you read my question, I already posted the controller method. (at)users is passed through the Index view where partial I posted is rendered and a method in the helper is called to get (at)users as follows: (at)users = User.all

Comment: The only relevant part of the controller is the Index method, which I posted in my comment and I edited my question to include it. No other parts of the controller are involved and the other two links in the partial are behaving properly.

Comment: The tone is an echo. I thought that the objective here is not to post my life story, but the relevant parts of an issue I'm dealing with. So, I am dealing with a View originating in the Index method. I posted all the relevant parts.

Comment: Nice update - to make it simpler, you may wish to use `except` like this: `resources :users, except: [:new, :create]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

Firstly, in your `destroy` method in the controller, you don't have any reference to the `@user` object:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def destroy
       @user.destroy # -> where is @user set?
    end
end
```

--

The `@user` variable needs to be defined before you can call `.destroy` on it. Usually, you'd do this:

```
def destroy
   @user = User.find params[:id]
   @user.destroy
end
```

In later versions of Rails, they actually use a method to set the `@model` variable with a `before_action` hook:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, except: [:create, :index]

    private

    def set_user
        @user = User.find params[:id]
    end
end
```

---

**Fix**

To fix the problem, you'll be best observing the error itself:

> undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass

This is standard issue - basically means you've not declared the variable on which you wish to call the `.destroy` method.

As mentioned above, you'll be best using a method to set this in your controller, allowing you to call `@user` in your relevant actions

Comment: Seeing that the other methods linked to from the partial are working properly, and this is Rails 4.1 (as in, if I don't set the user through the set_user and filter params through the user_params callbacks, then none of the links would work. So, I am looking now through my routes or the Index view for clues (these links to the User controller actions are going through the partial called form the Index action).

Comment: The solution was that I was missing something in routes.rb. I had the following: resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :index] so when I added destroy resources :users, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :index, :destroy] it worked

Comment: I am accepting your answer because it reminded me to check params[:id] vs only using id

Comment: Thanks for the updates :) So you got it fixed with `params`? Do you feel better now about fixing it/

Comment: It's a process Rich :-) The real problem was routes.rb, and it's non-standard because I am using Devise. This led to several convoluted attempts with links and methods, including using params[:id] vs trying to extract id form params in a helper method and using it. I posted the fix as an update to the original question.

Comment: Nice - let me check it out! Thanks for the updates again